# Add a section on my website header

Tags: css, header

Please go to [my website](http://www.b4bconsultancy.com/) . We build the site under Jupiter theme which uses bootstrap. I'd like to add one more section towards the right side of my logo which is CALL NOW and WhatsApp. Refer the below image.

[image: Header]

Answer (score 0):

Add this code after `<a></a>` which have http://www.b4bconsultancy.com/ link inside `.header-logo` div

```
<div class="rgt-side">
    <a class="call" href="#">
        <span>CALL NOW</span>
    </a>
    <a class="whatsapp" href="#">
        <img src="whats-app-logo.png" class="img-rseponsive">
    </a>
</div>
```

And put css styles as below

```
.mk-header .fit-logo-img a { floa:left; }
.rgt-side { display: inline-block; float: left; }
a.call { float:left; }
a.whatsapp { float:left; }
```

Try above code and ask any help you want.
Note - use neccerry styles for further adjustments such as `margin`, `padding` etc.

Cheers !!!